# Health Kit steps by movement for the day separated by device type

Tags: swift, healthkit

How to get data like in image below in Swift, im calculating steps per day and steps per hour but not sure how to get like below. I would like to get by device(watch, phone) steps per movement group not by a time interval?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used HKSampleQuery

```
func getStepCountForTodaySegmentedByMovement( complete: @escaping ([HKCumulativeQuantitySample]) -> () ) {
        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        
        guard let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
            fatalError("*** Unable to create a step count type ***")
        }
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: .distantFuture, options: .strictEndDate)

        
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: stepsQuantityType,
                                                predicate: predicate,
                                                limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                                sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: true)]) {
            (query, results, error) in
            
            
            complete(results as? [HKCumulativeQuantitySample] ?? [])
        }
        
        healthStore.execute(query)
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample query works if you want individual samples like what the Health app displays. Related point, in case it's useful, you can also get the stats separated by source if you pass [HKStatisticsOptions separateBySource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsoptions/1615479-separatebysource)